# org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am creating a ShoppingCart App using Spring-mvc.In dao layer I am using Spring-Hibernate ORM feature.

```
@Repository("baseDao")
public class BaseDaoImpl<T extends ShoppingCartEntity> implements BaseDao<T>
 {
   @Autowired
   protected SessionFactory sessionFactory;

   private Class<T> entityClass;

   public BaseDaoImpl(Class<T> entityClass) {
      super();
      this.entityClass = entityClass;
   }

   public Serializable save(T entity) {
      return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(entity); 
   }


   public void update(T entity) {
      sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().update(entity); 
   }


   public void saveOrUpdate(T entity) {
       sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(entity); 
   }
 }
```

CartDaoImpl.java

```
@Repository("cartDao")
public class CartDaoImpl extends BaseDaoImpl<CartMaster> implements CartDao {

   private Class<CartMaster> entityClass;

   public CartDaoImpl(@Value("com.orgn.shc.entity.CartMaster")Class<CartMaster> entityClass) {
       super(entityClass);
       this.entityClass = entityClass;
    }
 //other getter & setter
  }
```

I have a base entity class named ShoppingCartEntity.java.

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class ShoppingCartEntity implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
   //other fields
}
```

CartMaster.java:

```
   @Entity
   @Table(name = "SHOP_CART_MASTER")
   public class CartMaster extends ShoppingCartEntity {
  //other fields
   }
```

Now,during deployment of application in weblogic I am getting following exception:

```
   <28 Dec, 2017, 11:48:08,916 PM IST> <Error>  
   <org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet> <BEA-000000> <Context   
    initialization failed
    org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error   
    creating bean with name 'baseDao' defined in URL [zip:C:/Oracle 
    /Middleware/ORACLE_HOME/user_projects/domains/wl_server/servers 
    /AdminServer/tmp/_WL_user/shoppingcart/8i2b70/war/WEB-INF/lib 
    /wl_cls_gen.jar!/com/orgn/shc/dao/impl/BaseDaoImpl.class]: Unsatisfied 
    dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is  
    org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No 
    qualifying bean of type 'java.lang.Class<?>' available: expected at least 
    1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at   
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749)
```

Its spring-bean configuraation part as below

```
   <jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="jdbc/SHPDS"
    expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource" />

   <bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
      <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
      <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.orgn.shc.entity" />
      <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">20</prop>
        </props>
      </property>
   </bean>

  <mvc:annotation-driven />
  <context:component-scan base-package="com.orgn.shc" />


  <bean id="viewResolver"
class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

 <mvc:resources mapping="/assets/**" location="/assets/" />
```

My perception is that **@Value annotation** at constructor level is sufficient to inject the dependencies accordingly in sub classes.

Can anyone has any suitable solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `@Repository("baseDao")` from your `BaseDaoImpl` as it should not be created as a separate bean; instead, it should be only used as a parent for other DAO classes. I would also make it `abstract` and its constructor `protected` to avoid accidental instantiation.

Also, it looks like you need to change the constructor of your `CartDaoImpl` to the following:

```
public CartDaoImpl() {
   super(CartMaster.class);
}
```

And I don't believe you actually need `entityClass` field in `CartDaoImpl` as you know the class of your entity in this DAO: it's `CartMaster.class`. At the same time, in `BaseDaoImpl` that `entityClass` field may be useful to read entities from database (even though you don't have such methods).

Comment: I do have such method.Infact I am using a method getAll() which will be used  for createCriteria(entityClass).list()